# Oh man groupBy() and arrayToObject() are breaking me

Tags: javascript

So I have been working on some extra credit for my classes. I am very new to programming and have already sought help for this same assignment, I started rolling through and now am absolutely lost.

I need to define the two functions groupBy() and arrayToObect() as asked in the below test.

I'm not necessarily looking for the answer but if someone could help point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

What I have deduced is as follows:

1. I need to be using the spread operator ...
2. I need to create a newObj = {}

   a. and somehow push the element derived from the array into the obj
3. I need to take the individual values of the array and assign them as keys, with the variances as the properties of the key.
4. Bracket notation

I have been racking my brain for hours on this now and could really use some guidance!

```
describe('groupBy', function () {
        const input = [4.2, 6.1, 6.3]
        const result = groupBy(input, (el) => Math.floor(el))

        it('returns an object', function () {
            expect(result).to.be.an('object')
        })

        it('group array items together based on the callback return value', function () {
            expect(result).to.be.eql({
                4: [4.2],
                6: [6.1, 6.3],
            })
        })
    })

    describe('arrayToObject', function () {
        const input = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
        const result = arrayToObject(input, (word) => word + 's')

        it('returns an object', function () {
            expect(result).to.be.an('object')
        })

        it('object has original array elements as keys and the result of the callback as values', function () {
            expect(result).to.be.eql({
                cat: 'cats',
                dog: 'dogs',
                bird: 'birds',
            })
        })
    })
})

groupBy
Write a function called groupBy which takes an array and a callback. The function should return an object. Each return value of the callback should be a key of the object and the values should be the input element with which the callback was called.

arrayToObject
Write a function called arrayToObject which takes an array and a callback. The function should return an object. Each element of the input array should be a key of the returned object and the output from the callback with an element passed in as the corresponding value.
```

Comment: hey I'm sorry, I did say I didn't want the answer. I am just looking for a point in the right direction. I apologize for bothering you, I'm very new to programming.

Comment: Here's the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupBy) for the official `groupBy`. See if that will help.

Comment: Hence it's a class in school u are taking. So "So I have been working on some extra credit for my classes." means you need to improve your grades? Your teacher will know immediately you didnt write any posted answer here. Wouldnt it be more honest and *better* to learn how to code and re-take the course?

Comment: well actually it's non graded. I said 'extra credit' out of lack of better terms... it's simply extra practice. I'm doing a bootcamp with FlatIron schools.

Comment: no worries about it though, i understand I have made an annoying rookie mistake in asking for help

Comment: *"I have made an annoying rookie mistake in asking for help"* A rookie mistake is **not** to ask for help actually.

Comment: Huh `Array.prototype.groupBy` is not really standardized but still pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

These questions have been answered a million times on stackoverflow. Essentially what you want to be doing here is using the common js array functions `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `flatten`, ..., and think about how your problem can be expressed in terms of those.

A lot of real world code is transforming data like this, so it's good to be comfortable doing it.

Also realize that spread syntax copies the entire object which can be pretty inefficient. JavaScript doesn't have persistent data structures! It's usually better to just mutate — as long as your code is what "owns" the object.

```js
const groupBy = (elts, keyfn) =>
  elts.reduce((m, elt) => {
    const key = keyfn(elt);
    m[key] = m[key] || [];
    m[key].push(elt);
    return m;
  }, {});
```

```js
const arrayToObject = (elts, fn) =>
  elts.reduce(
    (obj, elt) => Object.assign(obj, { [elt]: fn(elt) }),
    {},
  );
```

Comment: ok this helps a lot. I was under the assumption that I had to figure it out without using the other methods. But it seems using them is the way!

Comment: Yeah these array methods essentially abstract away writing your own `for` loop and declaring variables. This is the idiomatic thing to do in JavaScript. A good exercise maybe is to try unrolling these to use for loops instead.

Comment: Um OP teacher going to know this not from him or her, simply by use of arrow functions. OP states in original question on working on "extra credit".

Comment: my instructor encourages us to seek help online for our assignments! I once again asked for a pointer in the right direction is all. Why are you so mad at me GetSet?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure this is academic dishonesty at any university, maybe not bootcamps idk... But hopefully you learned something and next time can do it on your own :)

Comment: Not in my bootcamp at least lol... Im supposed to be using a for loop in this assignment actually, so using reduce is going above and beyond. I'm gonna work on turning this into for loops myself and thinking that'll help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using a for loop!!

```
function groupBy(arr, callback) {
    const newObj = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (callback(arr[i])) {
            const key = callback(arr[i])
            newObj[key] = newObj[key] || []
            newObj[key].push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return newObj
}
```

```
function arrayToObject(arr, callback) {
    const obj = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (callback(arr[i])) {
            const key = callback(arr[i])

            obj[arr[i]] = obj[key] || callback(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return obj
}
```